# Spread Objects on Canvas minimizing overlapping

Tags: algorithm, optimization, geometry, computational-geometry

I am currently working on how to spread/distribute an amount of `n` objects, each with a position and radius-size, onto a 100x100 square canvas.

My initial idea was to randomly assign a 2D position to each of the objects within the boundaries. However, this might cause multiple objects to possibly end up very close together causing a huge overlap.

However, I would like to keep overlapping small if possible (of course, with increasing `n` there will be a point where not all object will fit onto the canvas without overlapping.

So now I am looking for some kind of iterative process that will move objects that are very close together further away, but making sure it won't end up on the position of another object.

Is there an existing algorithm for such problems? How would I start solving this?

Comment: You could use an approach similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing

Comment: Do the objects all have the same radius?

Comment: What is the shape of your objects?

Comment: Basically they are all square images, but with different objects on them on a transparent background. It's ok if the objects overlap a bit, so I limited it to them having the "collision radius". Also, the radius an be different on each object